# Equivalent java code statement for C code statement used in recursion

Tags: java, c, recursion

The code below does quick sort in C.I tried to translate the same code logic into java.But, i am unable to write the equivalent Java code statement for  "partition(&arr[left+1],size-left-1);" in the partition function below.Can anyone help?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int arr[8]={4,8,1,6,3,7,2,5};
        partition(arr,8);//Initial Calling of partition function
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d  ",arr[i]);
        return 0;
    }
     void partition(int arr[],int size)
    {
           if(size<2)
           return;
           int pivot=arr[rand()%size];
           int left=0,right=size-1,temp=0;
           while(left<right)
           {
               while(arr[left]<pivot)
               left++;
               while(arr[right]>pivot)
               right--;
               temp=arr[left],arr[left]=arr[right],arr[right]=temp;//swapping values

           }
        //partitioning and recursive calling
           partition(arr,left);
            partition(&arr[left+1],size-left-1);//The problem is to write an equivalent code for this
                                                //line in Java

    }
```

Comment: In one line: [`Arrays.sort(yourArrayHere)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do. You will need to do a more complex rewrite than just a line by line replace though. Use additional parameters to keep track of the index you want to consider the internal array starting from.

Comment: @Jems, i have tried the following rewrite,but it is generating so many exceptions that i am too boggled to think any solution.This is what i tried:

Comment: public class QuickSort {                                           public static void main(String[] args) {
     int arr[]={4,8,1,6,3,7,2,5}; partition(arr,0,7); int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }

Comment: static void partition(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
       if(arr.length<2)
       return;
       int pivot=arr[left];
       int temp=0;
       while(left<right)
       {
           while(arr[left]<pivot)
           left++;
           while(arr[right]>pivot)
           right--; temp=arr[left];arr[left]=arr[right];
           arr[right]=temp; }
        partition(arr,0,left);
        partition(arr,left+1,arr.length-left-1);}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Below is the equivalent Java code for the above (problem) partition function written in C.The initial call to partition function,say,from inside main, may be somewhat like this:partition(arr,0,arr.length-1);
Thanks for all your support and guidance

  static void partition(int arr[],int first,int last)
    {
        int left=first;
        int right=last,temp=0;
        if(left>=right)
            return;
        Random rnd=new Random();
        int pivot = arr[left + rnd.nextInt(right - left)];
        while(left<right)
        {
            while(arr[left]<pivot)
                left++;
            while(arr[right]>pivot)
                right--;
            temp=arr[left];
            arr[left]=arr[right];
            arr[right]=temp;
        }
        partition(arr,first,left);
        partition(arr,left+1,last);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without needing to handle pointers is to change the header like this:

```
void partition(int array[], int firstElement, int lastElement);
```

You can also try the function copyOf described here:

[copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int%29)

But you would have to reconstruct it back together since you're working on copies, and I doubt it would be much QUICKsort anymore

```
public static boolean[] copyOf(boolean[] original,
                               int newLength)
```

Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with false (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy but not the original, the copy will contain false. Such indices will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the original array.
Parameters:
original - the array to be copied
newLength - the length of the copy to be returned
Returns:
a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with false elements to obtain the specified length
Throws:
NegativeArraySizeException - if newLength is negative
NullPointerException - if original is null
Since:
1.6

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of pointers you need to specify start and end by parameters. Define you function like the following:

```
void partition(int arr[],int start, int end)
```

and instead of:

```
int left=0,right=size-1,temp=0;
```

do

```
int left=start,right=end,temp=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

C allows you to use pointers to refer to a different starting point in the same array. Java does not. You can only refer to the entire array.

But you can add the starting index as a parameter.

```
void partition(int arr[],int offset, int length) {
     ...
     partition(arr[], left+1, size-left-1); // check calculation, might be wrong :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The x argument refers to the "pivot " value. In any case you need to study how this algorithm works.

```
       public static int partition(
        int[] arr, int start, int end, int x)
    {

         int l = start,r = end;

         while (l<r ) {
            if (arr[l] < x)    
               { 
                l =l +1;
               }
            else  {                             

               int temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[r-1];
                arr[r-1] = temp;
               r = r-1;
            }

         }
         return l;
      }
```

Comment: Basically , i have written your partition method which was what you were asking.The hardest part in quicksort is to write the partition method. If you fully understand what the above code does,then you can have let's say another method call the partition method,make the appropriate swaps and then you need to sort the array for the two ranges. If this satisfies you, then please accept my answer. Thanks